# Creating A New Branch in Azure DevOps without being based on an Existing Branch

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to create a new Branch in ADO without it being based on an existing branch. Can someone let me know how to achieve that. At the moment, it appears I can only create to new branch if it based on on an existing branch. In the screenshot, the existing branch is 'main'. But as I mentioned I don't to base it on main

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from azure devops

You have to do this via the Git CLI

To create an orphan branch use the following command and replace branchname with the name of the branch you want to create. An orphan branch is a branch that starts without any commit history. It's used when you want to start a new line of development that doesn't share history with an existing branch.

```
git checkout --orphan branchname
```

Then run the following which will remove all files and directories from the current working directory. The -r flag stands for "recursive," which means it will remove directories and their contents recursively. The -f flag stands for "force," which allows the command to proceed without prompting for confirmation.

```
git rm -rf .
```

You can then run the following which will stage all changes in the working directory for the next commit. The '.' specifies that you want to add all changes in the current directory and its subdirectories.

```
git add .
```

You then want to commit your changes, replace "commit message" with the message you want to commit.

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

You can now push your changes, change branchname to the branch you have created

```
git push -u origin branchname
```

Once the push has completed you should see the new branch in the Azure DevOps UI (if you don't see it try refreshing).

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what you are trying to archive? Each branch should contain a source of content ([Git Branching - Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)). You may use a branch, tag, or commit. If you want to have your new branch based on the initial commit: you may find it, add some tag, and use it as a source.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't do it directly in the Azure Repo since git creates branches by pointing to a commit in an existing branch.

As a workaround, you can clone the Azure repo to your local machine. Then create an orphan branch.

1. Clone the repo: `git clone <repo url>`
2. Switch to the new orphan branch: `git switch --orphan <new branch>`
3. Make an initial commit: `git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit on orphan branch"`
4. Push the new branch to the remote repository: `git push -u origin <new branch>`